# Does success_url in PasswordChangeView override PasswordChangeDoneView?

Tags: django, django-views

When using `PasswordChangeView` in Django auth:

```
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_change.html',
        success_url='accounts/password_change_success.html'),
        name='password_change'),
```

Does the `success_url` override the `PasswordChangeDoneView`, as it does when `success_url` is passed in `PasswordResetView` and overrides `PasswordResetDoneView`? From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetDoneView):

> **PasswordResetDoneView**
>   This view is called by default if the PasswordResetView doesn’t have an explicit success_url URL set.

The docs are silent on the behaviour between `success_url` in `PasswordChangeView` and `PasswordChangeDoneView`.

Comment: Why do you add `.html` in your `success_url`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what's the correct syntax? `success_url=reverse_lazy('password_change_done')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) is the URL to which it *redirects* (through a 302 HTTP response) in case the form was successful.

In the [**`PasswordChangeView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView), we see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L328) that it uses:

> ```
> class PasswordChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
>     form_class = PasswordChangeForm
>     success_url = reverse_lazy('password_change_done')
>     template_name = 'registration/password_change_form.html'
>     title = _('Password change')
>
>     # ...
> ```

So in case you do *not* specify a `success_url` yourself, it will redirect to a view with the name `password_change_done`.

Comment: Thanks. If I pass the `success_url` in the URL path, can I use `success_url=reverse_lazy('password_change_done')` or do I have to reference an html template `success_url="accounts/password_change_success.html"`?

Comment: @alias51: you can use `reverse_lazy`, but you can *not* pass it a template. You can only pass it a *path*. This is basically what `reverse_lazy` does: it converts the view name to a path later.

Comment: @alias51: but setting it to `password_change_done` is of course not very useful here, since it is already set to `password_change_done`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am just using `password_change_done` as an example. Could you clarify the precise syntax for use in the URL path for me please? e.g. `success_url='password_change_done'`?

Comment: @alias51: for example `'password_change_done/` So the path part of the URL you see in the browser. But it is usually better to use a view name, with `reverse_lazy(..)` since if you later change the paths, then these will point to the new paths.

Comment: is that the template name or a file directory you are referencing? Sorry it's not clear.

Comment: @alias51: no not the template, the path in your `urls.py`. The templates are not exposed outside Django, so the browser does not know anything about templates.

Comment: @ Willem, sorry I mean is it the URL name or a folder you are referencing?

Comment: @alias51: a "folder" if you write it as `success_url='some/path'`, or a URL name with `success_url=reverse_lazy('some-view-name')`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: Django was not using my custom template because I used the same name for the html file. After changing it, it used the custom template.